# Ordenar Aniversariantes por Dia

Tags: php, mysql, data

Galera, precisava de uma ajuda para exibir na tela os Aniversariantes do Mês ordenado pelo dia, no banco ele puxa as informações do Sênior então a data vem ex: 1970-10-30, no meu controller está assim:

```
public function index()

{
    $condicoes['order'] = array('Funcionario.data_nascimento' => 'ASC');
    $condicoes['conditions'] = array(
        'Funcionario.situacao_afastamento <>' => 7,
        "DATE_FORMAT(Funcionario.data_nascimento, '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')"
    );
    $condicoes['limit'] = 59;
    $this->paginate = $condicoes;
    $this->set('aniversariantes', $this->paginate());
}
```

Nessa condição ele ordena primeiramente a data do ano :( e depois a data do mês.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

`$condicoes['order'] = array('DAY(Funcionario.data_nascimento) => 'ASC')`

Comment: Olá, então eu tentei isso uma hora mas ele não faz validação, se eu colocar dessa forma. :(

Comment: Como assim validação ?

Comment: Ele pula essa condição, e exibe os funcionários de forma aleatória.

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo `data_nascimento` ?

Comment: Campo do tipo DATE

Comment: Está usando algum `datatable` ?

Comment: Acabei fazendo na mão mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda. ficou assim:
[$aniversariantes = $this->Funcionario->query("select matricula, nome, data_nascimento, data_admissao, local_id  from 002_funcionarios WHERE situacao_afastamento <> 7 and extract(month from data_nascimento) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m') order by extract(month from data_nascimento), extract(day from data_nascimento)");
  ]